# piped program in sendmail's /etc/aliases

Tags: email, perl, sendmail

I'm trying some sort of auto-subscription via a homegrown script. I know it can be achieved by mailing lists such as Mailman but I also want to learn at the same time on how to do it by hand.

Here's the simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open ("RCV_MAIL", ">>/home/icasimpan/mail_received.txt") or die $!;
while(<STDIN>){
   print RCV_MAIL;
}
close(RCV_MAIL);
```

I attached the above script in /etc/aliases using the syntax:

```
subscribe: | /home/icasimpan/parse-subscribe.pl
```

and run

```
$ sudo newaliases
```

It's still a very bare script. Just testing out if I my syntax in /etc/aliases is correct.

But when I tried emailing subscribe@mydomaintests.tld, it returns something like:

```
Delivery failure 69
```

I'm using Lotus Notes so my google search directed me to [this link](http://www.symantec.com/business/support/index?page=content&id=TECH138158&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1296180757307). Apparently, something to do with the file...Not sure.

The command is executable, in fact I tried making it 777 and even created the mail_received.txt in the directory just to ensure I have no file permission problem but still the same.

Comment: Side note: I also tried my script from command line and it works....$ echo "CLI Test"|./parse-subscribe.pl and I could get the "CLI Test" inside mail_received.txt

Comment: Temporarily made /home/icasimpan 777 just to rule out permission problems but still the error is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're running a sendmail with smrsh set up (common in a lot of default configurations) you will need to run the piped command out of /etc/smrsh/.  It can either be a symlink or a copy of the script, but if sendmail has 'smrsh' defined, it will need to be run from that directory.  For example:

```
subscribe: | /etc/smrsh/parse-subscribe.pl
```

Check the sendmail documentation on smrsh for more details.

Answer (score 4):

You need to quote the "alias" if it has a space in it:

```
subscribe: "| /home/icasimpan/parse-subscribe.pl"
```

or remove the space:

```
subscribe: |/home/icasimpan/parse-subscribe.pl
```

Comment: This has been helpful to me too. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
open ("RCV_MAIL", ">>/home/icasimpan/mail_received.txt") or die $!;
while(<STDIN>){
   print RCV_MAIL;
}
```

is wrong.

If you're trying to print lines from STDIN to mail_received.txt, you would need:

```
open (RCV_MAIL, ">>/home/icasimpan/mail_received.txt") or die $!;
while (<STDIN>) {
   print RCV_MAIL $_;
}
```

because `print` with one argument takes the argument to mean the list to print, not the filehandle to print it to.

```
$ perldoc -f print
print FILEHANDLE LIST
print LIST
...
```

Also, no need for quotes around the filehandle name in `open`.  Just use `RCV_MAIL`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Mikel but it doesn't seem to work. I tried print $_ RCV_MAIL; or print RCV_MAIL $_; but no luck...

Comment: Hmmm. Could that be a typo error? I don't see a < in this perl reference http://www.perlfect.com/articles/perlfile.shtml

Comment: Sorry, my last comment was wrong.  Please ignore it.

Comment: `open("RCV_MAIL", …)` is horrible style, but it does work (Perl converts the string to a symbol). `print RCV_MAIL` works as well (it's a FILEHANDLE followed by an empty LIST, this only works if FILEHANDLE is a bare word IIRC).